# Gstreamer question

Tags: gstreamer

Recently I was learning gstreamer, and I have two questions.

I.

- I followed the basic tutorials about the section "HelloWorld". I git
  clone the code and use this  command on ubuntu: `gcc basic-tutorial-1.c -o basic-tutorial-1` pkg-config --cflags --libs
  gstreamer-1.0`
- and then run `./basic-tutorial-1`
- returns  `(basic-tutorial-1:14500): ERROR : 10:43:49.783: An error occurred! Rerun with the GST_DEBUG=*:WARN environment variable set. for more details. Trace/breakpoint trap (core dumped)`

I guess the URL `playbin uri=https://www.freedesktop.org/software/gstreamer-sdk/data/media/sintel_trailer-480p.webm` could not connect, maybe I should change the URL?

[image]

II.

- I followed Basic Tutorial 3: Dynamic pipelines, the tutorial says it will see the video just like HelloWorld, but the shell returns `Not all elements could be created.`

[image]